# Unable to set background image in Django

Tags: html, css, django

So I have a base.html file, to which I am trying to add a background image. This base.html file is inherited in all other system files, and I am hoping that adding the background image to base.html will automatically add the background image in all those files which inherit it.

I have a master.css file in my static/css path, and I am trying to add the background image to it by:

```
body{
  background-image: url(./background.jpeg); 
}
```

I have put the image in same folder as the master.css.

I am also attaching a screenshot of my file structure.
[image]

Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT 1:
adding my base.html where I am importing the css file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Coupon Portal</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

    <!-- Alternative to Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'couponSystem/css/master.css'%}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark mynav" role="navigation" id="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-nav align-items-center">

          <a class="navbar-brand mynav" href="{% url 'home' %}">The Coupon Portal</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Log out</a>
          {% else %}

            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Log in</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Sign up</a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container mycontent">
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock %}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Nalin. This didn't make it work.

Comment: I got it guys. I was passing in a wrong path of css file through my html, due to which entire css wasn't loading. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotation marks, try it like this:

```
body{
    background-image: url("background.jpeg"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem could be due to access permissions on the folder where the .jpeg image is placed.

If the image can be opened from browser directly as a url `(http://host-name/static/css/background.jpeg)`, then the background-image will work fine.

Comment: Image is opening in the browser this way. But isn't loading on my app.

Comment: Great. If the image is opening, then, can you check by setting the entire path to image in css, like:   background-image: url("/static/css/background.jpeg") ?

Comment: Hi Pavani. Thank you for your help. The issue was that I had not given the correct path of css file in my html. And as I am loading the image through css, it wasn't loading.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this, I thnik it will work.

```
body{
background-image: url("./static/css/background.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I got it, it was an error in importing the css file. Thank you for tsking out time to help me.